# Is setting XACT_ABORT "ON" recommended for read operation?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

Do we need to set XACT_ABORT "ON" in a stored procedure if it contains only a read operation?

Comment: What if tomorrow there's another operation *after* the read operation, do you expect your maintainers to remember to add it then? `XACT_ABORT ON` is rarely a *bad* idea. (In very rare circumstances you might want it `OFF` to do some interesting error handling in T-SQL itself -- but then you know what you're doing.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me in this case, it's about code conventions and following them. It will do no harm, for sure. But if you have a convention to always include `SET NOCOUNT, XACT_ABORT ON;` at the beginning of stored procedure - do it.

In our system, we are including `XACT_ABORT` on in routines having `TRY_CATCH` blocks and transactions. For example, the template is:

```
SET NOCOUNT, XACT_ABORT ON;

    -- CODE BLOCKS PREPARING DATA FOR CRUD

BEGIN TRY

    BEGIN TRANSACTION;
    -- CODE BLOCK PERFOMRING CRUD
    COMMIT TRANSACTION;

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH 

   IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
   BEGIN;
      ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
   END;

   -- LOG ERRORS DETAILS OR THROW ERROR;

END CATCH;

SET NOCOUNT, XACT_ABORT ON;

RETURN;
```